# How to pass variables from one JFrame to multiple JFrame in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, multiple-instances

I have been trying to do this a while back but failed to find a way.

My Java program contains four JFrames. `JFrame1` contains a table and a button that on clicking opens `JFrame2`. In `JFrame2` there is a table and two buttons that on clicking opens `JFrame3` and `JFrame4` which contain a table and Save button each.

Now what I want to do is that when a user enters data in `JFrame3` and clicks the save button the data is saved in the table of `JFrame2` and `JFrame1` repectively. Same thing for `JFrame4` but the data should be appended not deleted.

The data that is saved in the `JFrame1` from `JFrame3` and `JFrame4` is to be used to insert into the database.

These are my requirements. Can anyone help me out with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if they are not seperate programms, then you could use methods. If they are then there are several ways to communicate.

Comment: They are Separate JFrames. Can you specify some of the ways to communicate. # Kevin Esche

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is usually achieved through two approaches:

1. You can use the [`Card Layout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to avoid creating a new JFrame each time, but rather have one JFrame and replace its components. This would allow you to have one class which stores this data and then the logic to show it on your different screens.
2. If (1) does not do it for you, the other option would be to pass on a reference of the *parent* frame to the child. Thus, when you create an instance of `JFrame2`, you also pass it along an instance of `JFrame1`. Each JFrame class will have methods which are responsible for accepting information and displaying it according to your requirements.

Option 1 is usually the most recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameterized constructor or public variables or even public methods to pass values from 1 JFrame to another also using public static variables(not preferred) will be okay.